# Meteor CollectionFS - How can I modify my text file?

Tags: meteor, stream, filesystems, collectionfs

I have successfully uploaded a text file into a FS collection store. Now I want to modify the content of that text file or extract some information.

I can get the file object with:

```
var fileObj = myFSCollection.findOne({});
```

From what I have read, this is just a pointer to the file and not the file itself. How do I grab the text inside the text file so that I can modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the file itself with `fileObj.url()`. You cannot, however, *update* the file that CollectionFS has stored for you. You have to remove the original and insert a new one.

To download the file:

```
HTTP.get(fileObj.url(),function(err,result){
  if ( !err ){
    var content = result.content;
  }
});
```

Comment: console.log(fileObj.url()) gives me a path to the the text file. How do I read that text file and store the text in a variable so that I can see it?